# Python - Find maximum null values in stretch and replacing with 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with datetime and a column. I have to find maximum stretch of null values in a 'particular date' and replace it with zero.In example below, January 1st the maximum stretch null value is 3 times, so I have to replace this zero. Similarly, I have to replicate the process for 2nd January.

Note : Only the maximum stretch of null values has to be replaced with zero not the others.

Below is my sample data:

```
Datetime            X
01-01-2018 00:00    1
01-01-2018 00:05    Nan
01-01-2018 00:10    2
01-01-2018 00:15    3
01-01-2018 00:20    2
01-01-2018 00:25    Nan
01-01-2018 00:30    Nan
01-01-2018 00:35    Nan
01-01-2018 00:40    4
02-01-2018 00:00    Nan
02-01-2018 00:05    2
02-01-2018 00:10    2
02-01-2018 00:15    2
02-01-2018 00:20    2
02-01-2018 00:25    Nan
02-01-2018 00:30    Nan
02-01-2018 00:35    3
02-01-2018 00:40    Nan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert columns to floats and datetimes
df['X'] = df['X'].astype(float)
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], dayfirst=True)

#check missing values
s = df['X'].isna()
#create consecutive groups 
g = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
#get dates from datetimes
dates = df['Datetime'].dt.date

#get counts of consecutive NaNs
sizes = s.groupby([g[s], dates[s]]).transform('count')

#compare max count per dates to mask
mask = sizes.groupby(dates).transform('max').eq(sizes)

#set 0 by mask
df.loc[mask, 'X'] = 0
```

---

```
print (df)
              Datetime    X
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00  1.0
1  2018-01-01 00:05:00  NaN
2  2018-01-01 00:10:00  2.0
3  2018-01-01 00:15:00  3.0
4  2018-01-01 00:20:00  2.0
5  2018-01-01 00:25:00  0.0
6  2018-01-01 00:30:00  0.0
7  2018-01-01 00:35:00  0.0
8  2018-01-01 00:40:00  4.0
9  2018-01-02 00:00:00  NaN
10 2018-01-02 00:05:00  2.0
11 2018-01-02 00:10:00  2.0
12 2018-01-02 00:15:00  2.0
13 2018-01-02 00:20:00  2.0
14 2018-01-02 00:25:00  0.0
15 2018-01-02 00:30:00  0.0
16 2018-01-02 00:35:00  3.0
17 2018-01-02 00:40:00  NaN
```

EDIT: You can create `filtered` list of all datetimes for replace and chain together with mask for testing missing values by `&` for bitwise AND:

```
sizes = s.groupby([g[s & m], dates[s & m]]).transform('count')
```

All together:

```
df['X'] = df['X'].astype(float)
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], dayfirst=True)

#check missing values
s = df['X'].isna()
#create consecutive groups 
g = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
#get dates from datetimes
dates = df['Datetime'].dt.floor('d')

filtered = ['2018-01-01','2019-01-01']
m = dates.isin(filtered)

#get counts of consecutive NaNs
sizes = s.groupby([g[s & m], dates[s & m]]).transform('count')

#compare max count per dates to mask
mask = sizes.groupby(dates).transform('max').eq(sizes)

#set 0 by mask
df.loc[mask, 'X'] = 0
```

---

```
print (df)
              Datetime    X
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00  1.0
1  2018-01-01 00:05:00  NaN
2  2018-01-01 00:10:00  2.0
3  2018-01-01 00:15:00  3.0
4  2018-01-01 00:20:00  2.0
5  2018-01-01 00:25:00  0.0
6  2018-01-01 00:30:00  0.0
7  2018-01-01 00:35:00  0.0
8  2018-01-01 00:40:00  4.0
9  2018-01-02 00:00:00  NaN
10 2018-01-02 00:05:00  2.0
11 2018-01-02 00:10:00  2.0
12 2018-01-02 00:15:00  2.0
13 2018-01-02 00:20:00  2.0
14 2018-01-02 00:25:00  NaN
15 2018-01-02 00:30:00  NaN
16 2018-01-02 00:35:00  3.0
17 2018-01-02 00:40:00  NaN
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, thanks for your comment. What if I have one year data in 5 mins timestamps and I want to apply this process for only few selected dates not every date?

Answer (score 0):

interesting question.

My solution is written in scala, but I'm pretty sure there is a python equivalent to it.
First - the settings. I used a `case class KV`; in your example the key would be the date, and the value is the column X.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}

case class KV(k: String, v: Double)
val ds = Seq(("a", 0.0),
    ("a", Double.NaN),
    ("a", Double.NaN),
    ("b", Double.NaN),
    ("b", Double.NaN)).toDF("k", "v").as[KV]
val win = Window.partitionBy("k")

def countConsecutiveNans(s: String, iter: Iterator[KV]): Int = {
  (0 /: iter)((cnt: Int, kv: KV) => if (kv.v.isNaN) cnt+1 else 0)
}
ds.groupByKey(kv => kv.k).mapGroups(countConsecutiveNans)
```

The resulting Dataset is:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    2|
|    2|
+-----+
```

Hoped it helped!