# Finding maximum null values in stretch and generating flag

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have dataframe with datetime and two columns.I have to find maximum stretch of null values in  a 'particular date' for column 'X' and replace it with zero in both column for that particular date. In addition to that I have to create third column with name 'flag' which will carry value of 1 for every zero imputation in other two column or else value of 0. In example below, January 1st the maximum stretch null value is 3 times, so I have to replace this with zero. Similarly, I have to replicate the process for 2nd January.

Below is my sample data:

```
Datetime            X    Y
01-01-2018 00:00    1   1
01-01-2018 00:05    nan 2
01-01-2018 00:10    2   nan
01-01-2018 00:15    3   4
01-01-2018 00:20    2   2
01-01-2018 00:25    nan 1
01-01-2018 00:30    nan nan
01-01-2018 00:35    nan nan
01-01-2018 00:40    4   4
02-01-2018 00:00    nan nan
02-01-2018 00:05    2   3
02-01-2018 00:10    2   2
02-01-2018 00:15    2   5
02-01-2018 00:20    2   2
02-01-2018 00:25    nan nan
02-01-2018 00:30    nan 1
02-01-2018 00:35    3   nan
02-01-2018 00:40    nan nan
```

"Below is the result that I am expecting"

```
Datetime           X    Y   Flag
01-01-2018 00:00    1   1   0
01-01-2018 00:05    nan 2   0
01-01-2018 00:10    2   nan 0
01-01-2018 00:15    3   4   0
01-01-2018 00:20    2   2   0
01-01-2018 00:25    0   0   1
01-01-2018 00:30    0   0   1
01-01-2018 00:35    0   0   1
01-01-2018 00:40    4   4   0
02-01-2018 00:00    nan nan 0
02-01-2018 00:05    2   3   0
02-01-2018 00:10    2   2   0
02-01-2018 00:15    2   5   0
02-01-2018 00:20    2   2   0
02-01-2018 00:25    nan nan 0
02-01-2018 00:30    nan 1   0
02-01-2018 00:35    3   nan 0
02-01-2018 00:40    nan nan 0
```

This question is the extension of previous question. Here is the link [Python - Find maximum null values in stretch and replacing with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586712/python-find-maximum-null-values-in-stretch-and-replacing-with-0)

Comment: Do you need found maximum value per days? Or one maximum value per all days, here `3` ?

Comment: @ Jezrael , actually i wanted to find the maximum value for some filtered dates. In this case the date is 01-01-2018. But there can be possible that I have to use list of dates. This question is extension of the question that I have asked earlier. This is the link of my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586712/python-find-maximum-null-values-in-stretch-and-replacing-with-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create consecutive groups for each column filled by unique values:

```
df1 = df.isna()
df2 = df1.ne(df1.groupby(df1.index.date).shift()).cumsum().where(df1)
df2['Y'] *= len(df2)
print (df2)
                        X      Y
Datetime                        
2018-01-01 00:00:00   NaN    NaN
2018-01-01 00:05:00   2.0    NaN
2018-01-01 00:10:00   NaN   36.0
2018-01-01 00:15:00   NaN    NaN
2018-01-01 00:20:00   NaN    NaN
2018-01-01 00:25:00   4.0    NaN
2018-01-01 00:30:00   4.0   72.0
2018-01-01 00:35:00   4.0   72.0
2018-01-01 00:40:00   NaN    NaN
2018-02-01 00:00:00   6.0  108.0
2018-02-01 00:05:00   NaN    NaN
2018-02-01 00:10:00   NaN    NaN
2018-02-01 00:15:00   NaN    NaN
2018-02-01 00:20:00   NaN    NaN
2018-02-01 00:25:00   8.0  144.0
2018-02-01 00:30:00   8.0    NaN
2018-02-01 00:35:00   NaN  180.0
2018-02-01 00:40:00  10.0  180.0
```

Then get groups with maximum count - here group `4`:

```
a = df2.stack().value_counts().index[0]
print (a)
4.0
```

Get mask for match rows for set `0` and for `Flag` column cast mask to integer to `Tru/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
mask = df2.eq(a).any(axis=1)
df.loc[mask,:] = 0
df['Flag'] = mask.astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
                       X    Y  Flag
Datetime                           
2018-01-01 00:00:00  1.0  1.0     0
2018-01-01 00:05:00  NaN  2.0     0
2018-01-01 00:10:00  2.0  NaN     0
2018-01-01 00:15:00  3.0  4.0     0
2018-01-01 00:20:00  2.0  2.0     0
2018-01-01 00:25:00  0.0  0.0     1
2018-01-01 00:30:00  0.0  0.0     1
2018-01-01 00:35:00  0.0  0.0     1
2018-01-01 00:40:00  4.0  4.0     0
2018-02-01 00:00:00  NaN  NaN     0
2018-02-01 00:05:00  2.0  3.0     0
2018-02-01 00:10:00  2.0  2.0     0
2018-02-01 00:15:00  2.0  5.0     0
2018-02-01 00:20:00  2.0  2.0     0
2018-02-01 00:25:00  NaN  NaN     0
2018-02-01 00:30:00  NaN  1.0     0
2018-02-01 00:35:00  3.0  NaN     0
2018-02-01 00:40:00  NaN  NaN     0
```

EDIT:

Added new condition for match dates from list:

```
dates = df.index.floor('d')

filtered = ['2018-01-01','2019-01-01']
m = dates.isin(filtered)
df1 = df.isna() & m[:, None]

df2 = df1.ne(df1.groupby(dates).shift()).cumsum().where(df1)
df2['Y'] *= len(df2)
```

---

```
print (df2)
                       X     Y
Datetime                      
2018-01-01 00:00:00  NaN   NaN
2018-01-01 00:05:00  2.0   NaN
2018-01-01 00:10:00  NaN  36.0
2018-01-01 00:15:00  NaN   NaN
2018-01-01 00:20:00  NaN   NaN
2018-01-01 00:25:00  4.0   NaN
2018-01-01 00:30:00  4.0  72.0
2018-01-01 00:35:00  4.0  72.0
2018-01-01 00:40:00  NaN   NaN
2018-02-01 00:00:00  NaN   NaN
2018-02-01 00:05:00  NaN   NaN
2018-02-01 00:10:00  NaN   NaN
2018-02-01 00:15:00  NaN   NaN
2018-02-01 00:20:00  NaN   NaN
2018-02-01 00:25:00  NaN   NaN
2018-02-01 00:30:00  NaN   NaN
2018-02-01 00:35:00  NaN   NaN
2018-02-01 00:40:00  NaN   NaN

a = df2.stack().value_counts().index[0]
#solution working also if no NaNs per filtered rows (prevent IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds)
#a = next(iter(df2.stack().value_counts().index), -1)

mask = df2.eq(a).any(axis=1)
df.loc[mask,:] = 0
df['Flag'] = mask.astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
                       X    Y  Flag
Datetime                           
2018-01-01 00:00:00  1.0  1.0     0
2018-01-01 00:05:00  NaN  2.0     0
2018-01-01 00:10:00  2.0  NaN     0
2018-01-01 00:15:00  3.0  4.0     0
2018-01-01 00:20:00  2.0  2.0     0
2018-01-01 00:25:00  0.0  0.0     1
2018-01-01 00:30:00  0.0  0.0     1
2018-01-01 00:35:00  0.0  0.0     1
2018-01-01 00:40:00  4.0  4.0     0
2018-02-01 00:00:00  NaN  NaN     0
2018-02-01 00:05:00  2.0  3.0     0
2018-02-01 00:10:00  2.0  2.0     0
2018-02-01 00:15:00  2.0  5.0     0
2018-02-01 00:20:00  2.0  2.0     0
2018-02-01 00:25:00  NaN  NaN     0
2018-02-01 00:30:00  NaN  1.0     0
2018-02-01 00:35:00  3.0  NaN     0
```

Comment: @  Jezrael. Great! What if I have to use list of dates on the basis of that I have to mask and replace the maximum of null  with zero corresponding to only dates from the list, not all dates. This is question is the extension of the previous question which you have only answered. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586712/python-find-maximum-null-values-in-stretch-and-replacing-with-0

Comment: @Jazreal, Excellent ! This looks completely fine to me. Thanks a lot for putting the effort.